# How do I extract only a part of a list 'member' in PYTHON?

Tags: python, list, gis

My question is a bit basic, but as I'm a newbie in python (crossed over from GIS), please bear with me.

I have a python list which is based on the files the user inserts -

for example: `inputlist =["c:\\files\\foobar.shp","c:\\files\\snafu.shp"]`

how do I get the file names only (without the path or extesions) into a new list?

(desired output: `["foobar","snafu"]`  )

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python's list comprehensions for that:

```
new_list = [ splitext(basename(i))[0] for i in inputlist ]
```

Comment: `from os.path import basename, splitext`

Comment: thanks, it worked. Just one question: why isn't "import os" enough? (it worked only with  "from os.path import basename, splitext")

Comment: Because `import os` doesn't import the names into your current scope but only enables you to use `os.path.basename`.

Comment: @filmor, by "import the names" did you mean that with `import os' I can't assign the basename results to a variable? because if the answer's no, then I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: `import os` is equivalent to `os = __import__("os")` or something like that while `from os.path import basename` is similar to `import os; basename = os.path.basename; del os`. So in the first case you have the module available in your global namespace while in the second you only have one name from this module available.

Answer (score 2):

```
[os.path.basename(p).rsplit(".", 1)[0] for p in inputlist]
```

Comment: On Linux returns `['c:\\files\\foobar', 'c:\\files\\snafu']`, but probably works on Windows.

Comment: @eumiro:  It also works on -- say -- Linux, since `['c:\\files\\foobar', 'c:\\files\\snafu']` would be the correct answer if those were file names in a Linux file system.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os.path
extLessBasename = lambda fn: os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fn))[0]
fileNames = map(extLessBasename, inputlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also help you.

```
import os
inputlist =["/home/anupam/PycharmProjects/DataStructures/LogicalProgram/classvsstatic.py",
            "/home/anupam/PycharmProjects/DataStructures/LogicalProgram/decorators.py"]
filename_list = []
for i in inputlist:
    path_list =i.split('/')
    filename_with_extension = path_list[-1]
    filename_without_extension = os.path.splitext(filename_with_extension)[0]
    filename_list.append(filename_without_extension)

print(filename_list)
```

According to windows file path. You can split with '//' small change in my code.